# "+" is being converted to blank space after sending data to server

Tags: c#, urlencode

I am from java basically. But i supposed to modify a c# application. This application sends data of a text box to a server.(https connection)

everything is working fine.There is only one problem. If text in textbox is having "+" characters then on server side they are reaching as space. Means, if text box contains "amit+gupta" then on server side it is reaching as "amit gupta".

*I afraid there might be some other combinations which may cause problem further.

**Code**

```
System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
postData.Append("data1="+textBox4.Text);
postData.Append("&data2="+textBox5.Text);
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUrl);
myRequest.Method = "POST";
myRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

Stream newStream = myRequest.GetRequestStream();
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
```

**My observation**

As per my understanding, data should be url encoded first before sending to server. But...

> UrlEncode is missing

Visual studio 2008 has been setup for developing windows applicaion. In this(I had tried on 3 different machines), I am not able to find UrlEncode(). I had explored System.Web too But :-(

**My questions**;

1. Whether there is something wrong with above code
2. Whether UrlEncode() is available for web based project only
3. Is there any alternate of UrlEncode(). So i can use it in my application
4. Should i do some extra IDE settings or should i add some dll.

Comment: Check what version of the .net framework your project is using, you might need the full version (not client only).  And then url encode should be in system.web.

Comment: `"amit+2gupta"` should get decoded on the server as `"amit 2gupta"`. I don't know what happened to the 2.

Comment: @Gabe, you are correct this is for '+' only. not '+2'. thanks

Comment: @Stefan H,I am using Visual Studio 2008. And facing this issue on every machine, not only on mine.

Comment: You have to add a reference to System.Web.dll. The namespace System.Web is defined across several dlls, including System.dll (AspNetHostingPermission and AspNetHostingPermissionAttribute classes) and maybe that's the reason you can explore the namespace but don't find HttpUtility class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) in `System.Web`.

This requires adding a reference to `System.Web.dll`. If you can't add a reference to that, make sure you have the complete profile (not the client profile). If you require the client profile, you will have to implement your own encoding function.

Comment: It might be a stupidity, but since i am not .net coder so i expect this from me. My problem has been resolved by adding the reference to System.Web. I dint codfirme for the profile since the problem was solved. I'll mark the answer once the problem of '+' gets resolved.